# Python MSAL REST Graph: how to permanently delete a file from OneDrive to enable deletion of parent folder?

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-graph-api, delete-file, azure-ad-msal

I am working with the [MSAL](https://pypi.org/project/msal/) library to upload to, download and delete files and folders from a OneDrive repo.

My org is a retention policy that requires a folder to be empty before I can delete it. And that's how it works from the browser. That is, if I try to delete a folder with a file in it, it fails. If I then delete the file then delete the folder that works. However, I am getting a different behavior when doing this programmatically using MSAL.

When I issue a command like this to delete a file from the folder:

```
r = requests.delete("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/drive/root:/<path to folder>/<file in folder>", headers=requestHeaders)
```

and then try to delete the folder with:

```
r = requests.delete("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/drive/root:/<path to folder>", headers=requestHeaders)
```

I get an error like this:

```
'{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"Request was cancelled by event received. If attempting to delete a non-empty folder, it\'s possible that it\'s on hold", ...
```

When I open the folder in the browser, I don't see any files in it. It is my understanding from [**this post**](https://python.plainenglish.io/all-you-need-to-know-file-handing-in-sharepoint-using-python-df43fde60813) that when I delete a file, it goes to the Recycling Bin. Does it mean that to "really delete" and allow deletion of the parent folder, I need to also delete from this file from the bin? It seems that files deleted from the browser go to the bin too.

So the main question is really, what's the right way to programmatically delete a document to then be able to delete the parent folder, with the retention policy prohibiting deletion of nonempty policy, in place? TIA!